# How can i subtract a scalar value from a column in dataframe and pick only those rows which satisfy some condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame say

```
name age hb
ali   34  14
jex   16  13
aja   24  16
joy   23  12
```

I want to subtract column 'age' by 15  and column 'hb' by 10.

```
if the value age-15 < 10 AND hb-10 < 5 :
   select name
```

And the original dataframe should not be modified

Answer (score 1):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) or [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
mask = (df.age-15 < 10) & (df.hb-10 < 5)
s = df.loc[mask, 'name']
```

Or:

```
s = df.query('age-15 < 10 & hb-10 < 5')['name']
```

Or better, thanks, @pir:

```
s = df.query('age < 25 and hb < 15')['name']

s = df.loc[(df.age < 25) & (df.hb < 15), 'name']
```

If want all columns:

```
df1 = df.query('age < 25 and hb < 15')

df2 = df[(df.age < 25) & (df.hb < 15)]
```

Comment: `df.query('age < 25 and hb < 15')`

Comment: mask = (df.age-15 < 10) & (df.hb-10 < 5)
s = df.loc[mask, 'name'] this works fine for me.. can u pls tell how can i use abs() difference

Comment: Do you think `mask = ((df.age-15).abs() < 10) & ((df.hb-10).abs() < 5)` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do operate with different values for different columns then compare with other different values, again, for different columns, you can create Series with appropriate index values that align with the column names.  I must subset the original dataframe to just the columns of concern.

```
to_sub = pd.Series(dict(age=15, hb=10))
to_cmp = pd.Series(dict(age=10, hb=5))
df[df[['age', 'hb']].sub(to_sub).lt(to_cmp).all(1)]

  name  age  hb
1  jex   16  13
3  joy   23  12
```